# why IN clause not supported in with getEntityManager().createNativeQuery

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using eclipse link as JPA and Oracle as DB. I am using getEntityManager().createNativeQuery in java. In my query I want to use IN clause but it is not working and no exception as well.

From page user passes the input as 336885,56239,895423

Sample Query

```
"select emp_name from emp where emp_id in ( ?id)"    

query.setParameter("id", empBO.getEventIds());
```

I am using Java to convert the using split and concat

```
336885,56239,895423 to '336885','56239','895423'
```

but it is not working out for me.

I knew if we use  **JPQL** this going to work for me. the reason behind choosing Native is to avoid creating Model objects for tables.

### Update

I have used JPQL query since I need to deliver the code quickly. I have tried second answer what posted here. But no result came. when I get a free time I will try once again why IN is not working.

Comment: why are you wrapping numeric datatype with quotes?

Comment: What is "?id" ? JPA Native query parameters should be POSITIONAL. With Native queries the query is SQL and nothing else ... so if it "doesn't work" then the database is where your problem lies

Comment: here my actual column is String that is the reason i have quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this wouldn't work with JPA is the same why this wouldn't work directly with JDBC - it is lack of support in JDBC of multi-valued parameters.

When JPQL processor sees `in (?id)` it converts it into an expression that its underlying SQL engine could "understand" - usually, something that looks like this:

```
WHERE  emp_id IN (?id_0, ?id_1, ?id_2, ...)
```

This is supported by JDBC, so it executes without an error.

If you would like to perform a native query, you need to do this conversion yourself. Start with the template that you have, insert question marks for the number of IDs that you are sending, and bind IDs from the list to these parameters:

```
StringBuilder queryStr = new StringBuilder("select emp_name from emp where emp_id in (");
int[] ids = empBO.getEventIds();
for (int i = 0 ; i != ids.length() ; i++) {
    queryStr.append("?id_");
    queryStr.append(i);
}
queryStr.append(")");
... // Construct your query, then...
for (int i = 0 ; i != ids.length() ; i++) {
    query.setParameter("id_"+i, ids[i]);
}
```

Comment: sorry to say it is not working. Not getting any exception but no result are coming though it has a rows. Since i need to deliver the code i have implemented JPQL query which is working without any issues. I was trying all the time go with native query to avoid model object creation. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: JPQL ? This is "native" query ... i.e should be SQL

Comment: @NeilStockton I am contrasting SQL to JPQL in the way the parameters are processed. The answer talks about constructing SQL, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the log of jpa to see the request in you code.

`log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info<BR>`

or

```
<logger name="org.hibernate"><BR>
  <level value="info"/> <BR>
</logger><BR>
```

You can also try without parenthese :
"select emp_name from emp where emp_id in ?id"

Are you sure for `?` ?

```
"select emp_name from emp where emp_id in :id"
```

Regards,

Comment: Yes, in case of names query we will use this ":" but we have to use "?" in native query.